# Sending application-specific data from one SIP client to another during calls

Tags: sip, asterisk

I would like to send custom / app-specific data from one custom SIP client to another during calls. Instead of maintaining a separate connection to a separate server application, can this be done using Asterisk? It looks like there are 2 ways to do this:

- Using SIP INFO command.
- By initiating a custom RTP connection for this custom data to be sent over, using credentials from SIP.

My questions are:

1. Can Asterisk pass any SIP INFO messages / custom RTP streams coming to one client to another? How about in ConfBridge conferences?
2. How do I capture / stream this data using hooks provided by Asterisk in a separate server application (e.g. using AMI)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use for example video codec for send non-video stream. Asterisk will not check any way that stream before sending other party.

Yes,  you can use SIP message functional to send text data

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MessageSend

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+message

I am afraid conference will not allow do same, you have create your own app for that.

Also it seams you have use Kamailio/Opensips project for that, it allow more flexibility for sip message proxy/much more perfomance.